# Why awk arithmetic doesn't work?

Tags: awk, arithmetic-expressions

I have simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#NOTE - this script does not work!
#column=${1:-1}
column=1+1
awk '{print $'$column'}'
```

But when run

```
ls -la | ~/test/Column.sh
```

I receive always

```
1
1
1
1
```

What the problem?

Comment: There is no arithmetic in awk here, only in shell. And the shell does not support a=1+1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is equivalent to:

```
awk '{print $1+1}'
```

Awk tries to add one to the first column of the output of `ls -al` in your example, which is the file type and mode bits. That's not a number, so it gets converted to 0. Add one to zero, and you get your output.
See [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/html_node/Conversion.html):

> Strings that can't be interpreted as valid numbers convert to zero.

If you want the shell to calculate the number, try:

```
column=$(expr 1 + 1)
```

or even

```
column=$((1 + 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is pure bourne shell, instead of:

```
column=1+1
```

Try this:

```
column=`expr 1+1`
```

If it's bash, it should be:

```
column=$[1+1]
```

See here: http://linuxreviews.org/beginner/bash_GNU_Bourne-Again_SHell_Reference/#toc12